# how to show User id in message box if spinner value selected

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner

I want to show my user id in **message** **box**  but **spinner** value selected then it show the id but id doesn't not show. Here is my code.

Main class code:

```
public class AgentProgress extends Activity {

Spinner sp1, sp2;
ListView ls1;
ProgressBar pbbar;
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<AgentID> web;
ArrayList<String> wordlist;
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptername;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
static final String KEY_TABLE = "AGENTDATA";
static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "Parent_Agent_Name";
static final String KEY_USER = "Parent_Agent_Id_Pk";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_agent_progress);

    sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnames);
    sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spyear);

    ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<String>();

    int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    for (int i = thisYear; i >= 2011; i--) {
        years.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, years);


    sp2.setAdapter(adapter);


    pbbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
    pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    try {
        web = new ArrayList<AgentID>();
        wordlist = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (connectionAvailable() == true) {

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();

            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            WebServiceCAll com = new WebServiceCAll();

            AgentID agent = new AgentID();
            // final String string1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Agentid");

            String strXml = com.LoadAgent("LoadAgent");

            //messageBox("test", strXml);
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(strXml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TABLE);
            //String[] arList = null;
            //String[] arListkey = null;
            //  int conttotal=0;
            // looping through all item nodes <item>


            for (int j = 0; j < nl.getLength(); j++) {

                // creating new HashMap


                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                //map.put(KEY_AMOUNT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_AMOUNT));
                //map.put(KEY_USER,parser.getValue(e,KEY_USER));
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                //menuItems.add(map);

                Element e = (Element) nl.item(j);
                //messageBox("test", "fahad");
                agent.setID(map.put(KEY_USER, parser.getValue(e, KEY_USER)));
                agent.setname(map.put(KEY_AMOUNT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_AMOUNT)));
                names.add(map.put(KEY_AMOUNT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_AMOUNT)));


            }


        } else {
            messageBox("ERROR", "No Internet Service");
        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }


    adaptername = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);
    sp1.setAdapter(adaptername);
    AgentProgress.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adaptername.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int agr, long l) {

            HashMap<String,Object> obj=(HashMap<String,Object>) adaptername.getItem(agr);

            String pr=(String) obj.get(KEY_USER);

            messageBox("",pr);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });




}


        private void messageBox(String method, String message) {
            AlertDialog.Builder messageBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            messageBox.setTitle(method);
            messageBox.setMessage(message);
            messageBox.setCancelable(false);
            messageBox.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
            messageBox.show();
        }

        private boolean connectionAvailable() {
            boolean connected = false;
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                    connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                    connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_SUPL).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                //we are connected to a network
                connected = true;
            }
            return connected;
}
}
```

It show and error message in item selected listener on hash map Error is:

```
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to HashMap<String,Object>
```

Comment: String pr=adaptername.getItem(agr)

Comment: you are setting ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(); to adapter and while getting you call HashMap<String,Object> obj=(HashMap<String,Object>) adaptername.getItem(agr); .

Comment: How could it be possible to convert String to HashMap<String,Object> . if String is your key .Simply right  obj.get(adaptername.getItem(agr));

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get `Item` without getting an `Adapter`.

Replace

```
HashMap<String,Object> obj=(HashMap<String,Object>) adaptername.getItem(agr);
```

with

```
HashMap<String,Object> obj=(HashMap<String,Object>) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(agr);
```